# How do I create sites with vertical and horizontal sliding divs

Tags: jquery, html, grid, slide

I've seen a number of sites that follow a similar pattern. fullscreen, with divs that slide vertically with the up and down the the arrow buttons and each of those divs can slide horizontally if additional content is needed. I'm wondering how this is done (jQuery I know) but i figure there must be a larger framework that makes it easier. Here is an example of what I am referring to.

http://www.beoplay.com/

Comment: Maybe check this plugin out [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/adv.html).

Comment: The vertical scrolling could be done with [jQuery ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Scrollable. It allows you to use arrow keys to browse, and supports both horizontal and vertical sliding divs.

Read more about it and see a demo of what I'm talking about here: http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a fantastic help, 
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/gradientBackgrounds.html